# How to work calendar customization in SharePoint 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-server, calendar, customization

I was given a task to add a calendar on the intranet site that I am currently branding.

The calendar is supposed to show the schedule of various certifications courses with nice looking. I have used calendar overlay, added some CSS on a separate content editor, and the calendar look is some what improved. They are also interested in making a quick search on the calendar by event.

Did any one have worked on calendar customization?

Comment: Refer related [article1](http://microscoff.com/2017/02/09/filtering-sharepoint-search-calendar-dates/), [article2](https://www.quercussolutions.com/blog/index.php/sharepoint-2013-filter-display-start-time-content-query-web-part/)

Answer (score 0):

Sample script to overwrite OOB calendar function to do customization(filter for this case).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function searchCalendar() {
            window.location = window.location;
        }
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(CustomizeCalendarEvents, "SP.UI.ApplicationPages.Calendar.js");
        function CustomizeCalendarEvents() {            
            var _onItemsSucceed = SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarStateHandler.prototype.onItemsSucceed;            
            SP.UI.ApplicationPages.CalendarStateHandler.prototype.onItemsSucceed = function ($p0, $p1) {
                if (this.$K_1.$8G_0()) {
                    this.$28_1();
                    return;
                }
                this.$41_1 = false;
                if (this.$3G_1) {
                    this.$D_1.$4T_1();
                    this.$3G_1 = false;
                }
                if (SP.UI.ApplicationPages.SU.$2(this.$39_1[this.$j_1])) {
                    this.$39_1[this.$j_1] = [];
                }
                Array.addRange(this.$39_1[this.$j_1], $p0);
                this.$D_1.$7S_1(this.$j_1, this.$v_1, $p1, this.$39_1[this.$j_1]);
                this.$j_1++;
                this.$1h_1();
                alert('callback');
                //to do filter logic 
            }
        }
    </script>
    <input id="Button1" onclick="searchCalendar()" type="button" value="button" />
```

Get event properties for filter, you may check below thread.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/6ead033b-4f9c-48a6-9a6d-a395fdb424b9/share-point-2010-calendar?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious